# Import sample project into eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I know it may be a rookie question but I haven't done this before. How do I import android sample project like: https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html
to eclipse that have only res, src and manifest. I wish to know the right way and not copy - paste, also import project does not work here.

Comment: You unzip and then file/import/ android /existing code into workspace.

Comment: @DanM I have seen the example has the Manifest.xml so you just need import "Existing Android Code Into Workspace, read my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very easy:

Unzip the code, now you have the folder "`LocationUpdates`" containing the `Manifest.xml` file, `/src` and `/res` folders.

In Eclipse Go to: `File` > `import` > select `Android` Folder, `Existing Android Code Into Workspace` > 
Browse to the directory where your project to import is located, and check the option `Copy projects into workspace` > `Next` > Change if you want the project name in `New Project Name` > Finish

Refresh <kbd>F5</kbd> and Build your project

In other situations where we only have `/res` and `/src` folder, the only way is creating a new project.

Comment: I doubt this , because only src,res and manifest are not the entire project .. they need to have other files also in that project folder ,so only they can import ... address this issue

Comment: IF we have all the files including .project and .classpath we can use the option Import: "Existing Projects into Workspace"; if we have only the Manifest.xml, /res, /src, we have to use the option Import: "EXisting Android Code Into Workspace"; but if we only have /res and /src folders there´s no other way than creating a new project.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you should create a new Android application project , and copy paste the all the res,source and manifest will be only solution

Comment: I agree with this answer, but the advantage is that DanM has the Manifest.xml so he just need import the project with "Existing Android Code Into Workspace".=)